# Are two matrices having the same characteristic and minimal polynomial always similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

If it is not true, can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: Really? How about {{1,1},{0,1}} and {{1,0},{0,1}}? They are dissimilar but they have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @anon, that's wrong. Not even having the same characteristic and minimal polynomial is enough.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking there, hmm.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/56725 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83771

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider matrices in Jordan normal form with the same diagonal entries. The minimal polynomial just tells you the size of the biggest Jordan blocks (for the respective Eigenvalues). Example (for some $a$):

$\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & a & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 14):

Take the matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,\,,\,\,\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

These two matrices have $\,x^4\,$ as char. polynomial and $\,x^2\,$ as minimal one.

Try a nice exercise: prove that the condition *is sufficient* if the matrix is $\,n\times n\,\,,\,n\leq 3\,$

Comment: Insufficient in general though... $n>4$.

Comment: What about this... [0 0;0 0] and [0 1;0 0] have the same char poly but they aren't similar

Comment: Read the question carefully:same characteristic **and minimal** polynomials

Comment: Oooooooooooooops