# matrices with same minimal and characteristic polynomials are conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

Let $A$, $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. If $A$, $B$ have the same minimal polynomials and characteristic polynomials, then can we prove that $A$, $B$ are conjugate? i.e., does there exist $P\in GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ such that $PAP^{-1}=B$?

Prove or give counterexamples.

Comment: Unless you're limiting yourself to *invertible* matrices and working with that group, for *general* matrices the term is *similar matrices*, not *conjugate* ones.

Comment: Indeed so, @DustanLevenstein. That "less than" should have been "less", just as I myself wrote here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198857/are-two-matrices-having-the-same-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-always-si

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Consider two $4 \times 4$ matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 &  &  & \\    & 0 &  &  \\    &  & 0 & 1\\&&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &  & \\  0 & 0 &  &  \\   &  & 0 & 1\\&&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

(where I've written the matrices in Jordan block form; the omitted entries are zero.) Both matrices have characteristic polynomial $x^4$ and minimal polynomial $x^2$, but they are not similar.