# Diagonalizable traceless matrices with the same minimal polynomial that are not similar

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Question:** Can we find two diagonalizable traceless matrices $A,B\in M(n,\Bbb C)$ with the same minimal polynomial but such that $A$ and $B$ are not similar?

There was a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198857/are-two-matrices-having-the-same-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-always-si). In that case the answer was positive, but they don't assume that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable and traceless.

---

**Attempt:** The fact that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable with the same minimal polynomial means that their set of eigenvalues are the same. Hence, they could only differ in the multiplicities of their eigenvalues. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\in\Bbb C$ be those distinct eigenvalues. Wlog, $A$ and $B$ are already diagonal, so
$$A={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k,\ldots,\lambda_k),$$
where $\lambda_j$ is repeated $m_j$ times, and
$$B={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k,\ldots,\lambda_k),$$
where $\lambda_j$ is repeated $n_j$ times. Now the condition that they are traceless means
$$
\begin{align}
m_1\lambda_1+\cdots+m_k\lambda_k&=0\\
n_1\lambda_1+\cdots+n_k\lambda_k&=0.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the question can be reformulated as follows:

> **Reformulation:** Can we find distinct $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\in\Bbb C$ and two different vectors $(m_1,\ldots,m_k),(n_1,\ldots,n_k)\in(\Bbb Z_{\ge 1})^k$ such that
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> m_1\lambda_1+\cdots+m_k\lambda_k&=0\\
> n_1\lambda_1+\cdots+n_k\lambda_k&=0 \\
> m_1+\cdots+m_k&=n_1+\cdots+n_k?
> \end{align}
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1+2+2-2-2=1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1+2-2-2-2$