# when two matrices are similar in $M_n( \Bbb{C} )$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Let $M_n( \Bbb{C} )$ be set of all $n \times n$ matrices over $$\{\Bbb{C}\setminus \Bbb{R} \}$$ then for $A,B \in M_n( \Bbb{C} )$ are similar iff minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $A,B$ are same?
Is this statement true! It is obvious that converse is true but I am not sure about the other way around!
I know that above statement is not true if matrix is over $\Bbb{R}$ can we generalise it over $\Bbb{C}$ ?
**I am asking specifically for matrix with pure complex entries!**

Comment: No, it is not equivalent. Did you search this site already?

Comment: The matrix counter-examples are even over $\Bbb Q$, hence also over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Edited my question, please read it again!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Seems that even $0$ is not allowed…

Comment: You have edited the question too often now. How can someone give then a valid answer?

Comment: It is final version! Sorry for trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple examples. 
$$
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}
\newcommand\rme{\mathrm e}
\newcommand\imu{\mathrm i}
\newcommand\diff{\,\mathrm d}
\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
\renewcommand \epsilon \varepsilon
\newcommand\trans{^{\mathsf T}}
\newcommand\F {\mathbb F}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}
\newcommand \N {\Bbb N}
\newcommand\bm\boldsymbol
\bm A = \imu \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & & \\ & 1 && \\ &&1&\\ &&&1
\end{bmatrix}, \bm B = \imu\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & & \\ & 1 && \\ &&1&1\\ &&&1
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
then both the minimal polynomials are $(x-\imu)^2$ and the characteristic polynolmials are $(x-\imu)^4$, but $\bm A, \bm B$ are not similar.

The statement is true if $n \leqslant 3$.

Comment: But this is nothing more than the examples from the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198857/are-two-matrices-having-the-same-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-always-si).

Comment: A go-to response for this question :)

Comment: I am Asking about matrix with pure complex entries!