# Two complex matrices with same rank are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

If two matrices with pure nonzero complex entries

> in $M_n( \Bbb{C}) $

are of the same rank, then can we say that both matrices are similar?
Edit:

> Where the term 'pure nonzero complex entries' indicates that $\forall \ a_{i,j}$ entry in $A \in M_n( \Bbb{C} ), a_{i,j} \ $ has nonzero imaginary part. Where $i$ runs from $1,2 \cdots ,n$ , and so is $j$

Comment: If you're not happy with the  answers below, consider the $1\times 1$ case:  the rank one 'matrices' $(i)$ and $(2i)$ are not similar.

Comment: Your counterexample is kind of trivial but satisfying! Can you explain further, what **minimal extra** conditions do I need to bridge the gap!?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468182/when-two-matrices-are-similar-in-m-n-bbbc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take, for instance,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2i&i\\-2i&-i\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{bmatrix}i&i\\-i&-i\end{bmatrix}.$$Both of them have rank $1$. But they are not similar. For instance, $A^2\neq0$, but $B^2=0$.

Comment: There was something in there about nonzero entries.

Comment: I missed that and I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Pure complex entries means every entry has nonzero imaginary part!

Comment: @Alfha Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes! And eigen values and trace of both matrices aren't same too!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: What can you say of the determinant of similar matrices?

Comment: Determinant is necessary condition for similarity of two matrices, not sufficient condition!

Comment: Since it's necessary, if you can find two matrices that fit your description but have different determinants, then...?

Comment: That is where I'm stuck! How to construct such matrices?

Comment: By chance, it would be very unlikely to stumble upon matrices with the same determinant.

Comment: You aren't understanding me! If I'll be able to construct one or two such pair of matrices that doesn't mean I've the power to assume it as **generalized result !**

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The generalized result you seek to prove is false; to that end, all that's needed is to provide a counter example. If instead you wish to ask 'under what conditions can we say that matrices with these properties are similar?', then your question should reflect that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102089/discussion-between-alfha-and-fimpellizieri).