# Conjecture: Any two matrices of size $n×n$ with same characteristic and minimal polynomial are similar implies $n\le 3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial, similar-matrices

Notations:

$\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R}) $: the set of all $n×n$ matrices over $\Bbb{R}$

$\chi_A(x)$: Characteristic polynomial of $A$

$m_A(x)$ : Minimal polynomial of $A$

$A\sim B$ : $\exists P\in Gl_n(\Bbb{R})$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$

---

**Conjecture**: $(\forall A, B\in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ with $\chi_A=\chi_B$ and $m_A=m_B$ implies $A\sim B) $implies $n\le 3$

---

Attempt:

Let's work with converse.

For $n\ge 4,\exists A, B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R}) $ with $\chi_A=\chi_B$ and $m_A=m_B$ such that  $A\not\sim B\tag{1}$

Special cases :

$\boxed{n=4}:$

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

$B=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

$$\chi_A(x) =x^4=\chi_B(x) $$ and $$m_A(x) =x^2=m_B(x) $$

$\begin{align}\textrm{rank}(A)=2\neq 1=\textrm{rank}(B) &\implies A\not\sim B\\\end{align}$

$\boxed{n=5}$:

$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

$B=
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

$$\chi_A(x) =x^5=\chi_B(x) $$ and $$m_A(x) =x^2=m_B(x) $$

$\begin{align}\textrm{rank}(A)=2\neq 1=\textrm{rank}(B) &\implies A\not\sim B\\\end{align}$

$\boxed{\text{General cases}(n\ge 4)}$:

Strategy: Find two nilpotent matrices $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ with degree of nilpotency $2$ and $\textrm{rank}(A) \neq \textrm{rank}(B)$

$A=(a_{ij}) $ and $B=(b_{ij}) $

where
$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 &(i,j)\in\{(2,1),(n-1,n)\}\\0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$b_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 &(i,j) =(2,1)\\0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then $$\chi_A(x) =x^n=\chi_B(x) $$ and $$m_A(x) =x^2=m_B(x) $$

$\begin{align}\textrm{rank}(A)=2\neq 1=\textrm{rank}(B) &\implies A\not\sim B\\\end{align}$

---

For $n\le 3$ and $\forall A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ with $\chi_A=\chi_B $ and $m_A =m_B $ implies $A\sim B $([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56725/977780))$\tag{2}$

Conclusion: $(1) $ and $(2) $ together implies that the conjecture is true.

---

Question:

> 1. Is my attempt correct?

> 2. What about the direct proof $[$ starting with any two matrices having the said properties and then showing $\textrm{deg}(\chi_A) =\textrm{deg}(\chi_B)\le 3]$ ?

Note: Two matrices are similar iff both have the same Jordan normal form upto the permutation of Jordan blocks.

Comment: Your idea  works, but your examples are not entirely correct, since your minimal polynomials are certainly not $X^2$, but  $X^{n-2}$. However, they still do their job.

Comment: This is already known, e.g., see [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/two-non-similar-matrices-having-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials/), or posts on this site (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56673/does-equality-of-characteristic-polynomials-guarantee-equivalence-of-matrices) for your examples.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe the proof of "$(\forall A, B\in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R}) $ with $\chi_A=\chi_B$ and $m_A=m_B$ implies $A\sim B) $ implies $n\le 3$ can't be found on MSE?

Comment: $(1)$ and $(2)$ are on MSE, and as you say yourself - this immediately proves your conjecture. I didn't search yet, but I think it is also stated on MSE somewhere (but I did not downvote!)

Comment: I only found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198857/are-two-matrices-having-the-same-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-always-si), where DonAntonio states it as "a nice exercise", but does not prove it. I remember it was proved somewhere on MSE, but cannot find it right now - so perhaps you are right.

Comment: Just take block-diagonal matrices whose first diagonal block are the matrices A and B of your first example, and all other entries are 0.