# All Possible Jordan Canonical forms, given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ complex matrix with two distinct eigenvalues $e_1, e_2$. Write all possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$ and find the spectrum of $A$, in case(1) $A^{2}=A$ and case(2) $A^{2}=I$

So I know that the characteristic polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ is always fully reducible, which implies that there are three eigenvalues for A, right? Then $e_3$ is either equal to $e_1$ or $e_2$. Then to find each $J_{i}$, would I find the kernel of each eigenvalue?

Comment: Also, I think that for case 2, the spec is just the set {-1,1}.

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan Canonical Form of a $3 \times 3$ complex matrix is completely determined by its characteristic and minimal polynomials. You already know you have two distinct eigenvalues $e_1$ and $e_2$. Now if the third eigenvalue $e_3$ is different from those two, then your matrix is diagonalisable. If it is equal to $e_1$ or $e_2$, say $e_1$ for now your characteristic polynomial is $\chi(t) = (t - e_1)^2(t - e_2)$ while the minimal polynomial is either equal to the characteristic polynomial or is $(t-e_1)(t-e_2)$.

See this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83771/jordan-canonical-form-determination/83779#83779) for an explanation of why in the $3 \times 3$ case the characteristic and minimal polynomials completely determine your jordan form.

Comment: thank you but some questions. So the matrix representation would be just two blocks with the first one just being a $1x1$ matrix and the second being a $2x2$?

Comment: @JackinAstoria Well it depends on whether the characteristic polynomial is equal to the minimal polynomial or is not. See my post in the link.

Comment: I took a look and read it, but how can I determine the minimal polynomial, would I just assign it WLOG to either c1 or c2?

Comment: @JackinAstoria By the way in case (1) and (2) I believe $A$ is always diagonalisable.

Comment: @BenjaLim - Indeed in both cases $A$ is diagonalisable as the minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $A^{2}=A\implies A^{2}-A=0\implies A(A-I)=0\implies P(A)=0$
where $P(x)=x(x-1)$ so the minimal polynomial divides $P$ .

**Hint 2:** The roots of the minimal polynomials are all the roots of
the characteristic polynomial and there are $2$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused. I think I remember, although possibly wrong, that eigenvalues for matrix A^2 are just the eigenvalues for matrix A, squared. So then in my OP, the spectrum in case 1, would that just be $c_{1}^{2}$ and $c_{2}^{2}$? Case 2?

Comment: I say that from both hints you can deduce exactly what are the eigenvalues, can you see that ?

Comment: feeling dumb here, is it 0,1?

Comment: Can you first tell what is the minimal polynomial by using hint 1 ?

Comment: The minimal one is 0?

Comment: No, the minimal polynomial is never $0$, by definition (for example the minimal polynomial is defined to be monic)

Comment: I'm not understanding, then the minimal is 1, but then we do not have two distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Why do you think the minimal polynomial is $1$ ? is $A$ a zero of this polynomial ? (better yet - does this polynomial have any zeros ?)

Comment: I am very confused and am having a hard time following you.

Comment: Okay, 1 has to be a root as that solves that polynomial, but so does 0 but you're saying 0 can't be.