# Similar matrices and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Any two matrices M and N which have the same characteristic and minimal polynomial are similar ?

Is there any easier way to explain ?

I tried as M and N have same Jordan forms. So let Jordan form J of M implies  J = P^-1MP and Jordan form K of N give K = Q^-1NQ & J=K gives after solving N = R^-1MR where R = PQ^-1. Gives M and N are similar.

Comment: M and N are similar matrices ? They have same characteristic and minimal polynomials .

Comment: If their size is $\le 3$, yes. If it's $\ge 4$, not necessarily.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: See "[Jordan Canonical Form determined by characteristic and minimal polynomials in dimension $3$, but not beyond](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83771/jordan-canonical-form-determined-by-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomials-in-di)".

Comment: The same procedure can be applied to matrices over any algebraically closed field. Moreover, since [two matrices in $M_n(\Bbb K)$ are similar if and only if they are similar in $M_n\left(\overline{\Bbb K}\right)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions), the result can be extended to arbitrary fields.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli is there any easier way to explain it ?

Comment: Well, technically, just the counterexample in $M_4(\Bbb C)$ (which actually works for $M_4(\Bbb K)$) solves your question. As for the remaining part, in my humble opinion, I think the use of Jordan canonical form, for the complex case, is somehow needed, because the proof I am aware of ultimately boils down to "if you classify the possible Jordan forms of a $n\times n$ complex matrix, it turns out that there are not that many of them for $n\le 3$, while for $n>3$ there are".

Comment: I don't know if the generalization to arbitrary fields was within your interests, but I think that, as algebraic as the details may be, the lemma on similarity that I quoted (at least in the version I used) is somehow needed to face the full problem. If you were interested only in complex matrices, you can ignore it.

Comment: Just abit difficult for me  .  can you explain more easily ?

Comment: As I said, I cannot.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli ok thank you for you time and help ☺